# Обязательно ли создавать все объекты с припиской @FXML только в Контроллере?

Tags: java, javafx, controller

Могу ли я для удобства в одном java файле создать все объекты типа Button, в другом только TextField, или все объекты (как на скрине) должны создаваться только в контроллере?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Контроллер связан с файлом xml разметки, если у вас в одном файле только кнопки, а в другом только поля, то так и получится.

Comment: Если я просто создаю новый java файл, и там создаю fxml элементы, то программа не запускается, наверное как раз потому, что этот файл не привязан к fxml. Получается его нужно привязать, или как?

Comment: Вероятно программа сообщает о причине почему она не запускается. Аннотация @FXML нужна для установки значений через рефлексию

Comment: Я нашёл на зарубежных источниках, что нельзя нельзя иметь несколько контроллеров и  один fxml, и, насколько я понял, нужно разбивать программу на несколько fxml файлов. Но если так, то размещая с помощью одного fxml только кнопки, с помощью другого поля,  т.д., я не смогу увидеть общий дизайн программы.